# Rapid computation and visualization of intersections of polygon layers

Tags: postgis

I'm brand new to the PostGIS world and am hoping to get some guidance on realizing a vision of interactive geospatial analysis I'm holding.

I would like to build a web app that facilitates rapid identification of regions where a series of conditions are true.

PostGIS seems like precisely the backend database I need to leverage to

1. persist individual polygon layers representing different attribute layers,
2. rapidly compute intersections of selected layers, and
3. rapidly generate vector tiles for responsive multi-scale visualization.

**What I'm wondering about is what format the individual polygon layers should be persisted in to minimize the total delay from query submission to vector tile rendering?**

**Is it possible / preferable to represent the individual layers as vector tiles and perform intersection computations on vector tiles? Or must set operations be done on polygon layers first and the result converted to vector tiles**

I assume the PostGIS function ST_AsMVT might play a key role in this pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite broad as question, so I will try to give you a few tips about what I understood of your problem:

- You should use postgis table(s) storing `geometry` (or `geography`, depending on your projection) with proper indexes on these columns, to be able to easily compute/intersects on demand, the cutting in tiles and transformation in MVT should be after (note that you need to first select the area where to compute, aka the tiles asked, to avoid computing on your whole data when only a portion where asked)
- If you have several layer that you need to intersects, I would say it's probably more logical to store these in one table for each layer, but it can depends of your use cases and the number of layers.
- There is a tool made to easily serve MVT tiles from one or several postgis tables: [pg_tileserv](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv). You can simply serve your postgis tables, or even create a function in the proper format in postgres (for example taking parameters and doing the intersection between tables, there is [example in the doc](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv#function-layer-examples) where you can see the process, like passing a parameter and getting the extend of the tile asked to select the zone). I recommend it, at least to easily test serving tiles.